"message": "The request uses the <code>mine</code> parameter but is not properly authorized.",
I am building a youtube clone using youtube v3 api. I used firebase for google sign in.
I added scope for youtube using following code :
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

I am sending a http request using axios to following URL :
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&forChannelId=UC0wQBs1G70mUxfxuQ6uhZKA&regionCode=IN&mine=true&key=AIzaSyDwr3F14VsY3rXqmq9dGzR2G_Oyb4QNGVQ
But it gives the following error :
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The request uses the <code>mine</code> parameter but is not properly authorized.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request uses the <code>mine</code> parameter but is not properly authorized.",
        "domain": "youtube.parameter",
        "reason": "authorizationRequired",
        "location": "mine",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }

I used the following code for sending the request :
useEffect(() => {
    const getSubscriptionData = async ()=>{
      try {
        console.log(token);
        const value = await axios.get(YT_SUBSCRIPTION_URL , {
          params : {
            part : 'snippet,contentDetails',
            forChannelId : data.snippet.channelId,
            mine : true,
            key : YT_API_KEY,
            access_token : token
          },
          headers : {
            Authorization : `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        })
        console.log(value);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    getSubscriptionData();

  }, [data])

what's the problem ?

You have : "reason": "authorizationRequired" in response. Are you sure your request fullfills all requirements?

the api asks for only access_token and I provided it. And also it is giving error code 400 not 401.

You have a 401, not 400
